# Error while copying content to a stream.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am exporting excel file using WebApi but it throws an exception and I don't know why. I googled it and haven't found any solution.

Exeption:

```xml
    <Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Error while copying content to a stream.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<HandleCompression>d__17.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    </StackTrace>
    <InnerException>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Cannot access a closed Stream.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.ObjectDisposedException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
    at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed() at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Position() at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartAsync()
    </StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
    </Error>
```

My Code is :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/AddPatient/ExportToExcel")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExportToExcel()
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream dataStream = Utility.GetFile();

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Test.xlsx";
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**GetFile** function as below for getting excel memorystream
Note: using NPOI i am createting excel file

```
public static MemoryStream GetFile()
        {
            MemoryStream stream =null;
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ISheet sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Test");
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
            var cell = row.CreateCell(0);
            cell.SetCellValue("Test");

            using ( stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.Write(stream);    
            } 

            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: it seems  Utility.GetFile got  an error,please paste it.

Comment: There is no point to have the `try catch` block if you just rethrow the exception...

Comment: You're disposing `stream` and *then* returning it? Then you're getting `ObjectDisposedException`? Not really sure what the question is here.

Comment: What does `Utility.GetFile()` do? Does it create the file in memory or does it create a file from disk? In any case, you can use `return File(...)` to return either a stored file or a stream. A MemoryStream is nothing more than a wrapper over a `byte[]` array and disposing it doesn't release any resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful when dealing with the stream object.

But I think your function to get `dataStream` also wrong. More code perhaps?

```
try
{
    using(MemoryStream dataStream = Utility.GetFile())
    {
      // read from beginning 
      dataStream.Position = 0;

      HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
      httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
      httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Test.xlsx";
      httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

      return httpResponseMessage;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Your `GetFile` cannot wrap using statement, that will close your memory stream object.

```
 // try this
 public static MemoryStream GetFile()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        // do your thing
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Test");
        var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
        var cell = row.CreateCell(0);
        cell.SetCellValue("Test");

        wb.Write(stream);    
        // reset position here
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Now new error is cominh: cannot access a closed Stream

Comment: @JasminSolanki normally that's because you access it when it already "close", you need wrap with using statement, so that your object will not dispose when you want to use it

Comment: @JasminSolanki you cannot use using statement in your getFile function, that's why you getting the same error. Remove that using statement.

Comment: Yes i changed it but still stream is closed

Comment: Why use this code instead of a simple `return File(stream,..);`? The actual fix is to avoid disposing the MemoryStream, or use a byte[] buffer instead. A MemoryStream is nothing more than a wrapper over a byte[]

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I uncertain what he trying to do, but I agree with you if just want memory stream, the answer will be like that, if he wants do fileStream, then return File will be useful.

Comment: @KiraHao `return File` also accepts a stream as a parameter, as well as content disposition, filename and content type parameters. Explicitly creating a StreamContent won't solve the problem.

Comment: ya, I know that, let him decide what he wants to do. I will update my answer for return File too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the reason I don't suggest is because of return File need specific one physical file so that you can return it, maybe stick with return MemoryStream best for him.

Comment: @JasminSolanki in case my answer help you, appreciate you can mark as accept answer. Thank you.